# Where did my friend come from?

Tags: riddle

My friend is a ten year old unremarkable human.
His parents are also unremarkable humans.
However, his parents are old enough to have been born in three "different" countries.

He was born in the last two of those countries.
Both of these countries are very, very "similar".
What country did my friend come from? Or rather... what is his current country?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He could be from

> North Macedonia, which was called just Macedonia until recently. (Not sure if that counts as "different" countries.) It was part of Yugoslavia when his parents were born.

Comment: That was quick.. was it really that obvious? :/ Oh well...

Comment: I did not get it. Could you elaborate please?